# Нужно ли здесь тире?

Tags: пунктуация

*– Ручки не будет? – спросил юноша, расписывая свою на форзаце записной книги.*

Нужно ли после слова "свою" ставить тире?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повторение одного слова (ручки, ручку) в рамках оного предложения выглядит плохо с точки зрения стилистики. Так что отсутствие слова **ручку** после **свою** вполне оправдано, это нельзя считать пропуском слова. *Тире после слова **свою** не нужно.*